# not able to launch chrome brower using webdriver, am using chrome v52.0 and chrome driver v2.22

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//usr/bin/google-chrome");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("www.flipkart.com");
```

error log

> Aug 06, 2016 11:04:17 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
>        INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2).    [/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome, --port=17607][ {}]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly without seeing more of the stack trace and knowing more about your system setup. The first thing, though, is to make sure you have the most current Selenium (v. 2.53.1 as of 8/6/16 ... not counting the beta of v3) and the most current Chrome WebDriver (v. 2.23 as of 8/6/16). I am not sure of your Selenium version but your stated chrome driver can be updated. It is best to make sure you keep selenium and web drivers up to date as much as possible.

Chrome web driver download link:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads